# Inserting Data Into Mongodb using C#

Tags: c#, json, mongodb, bson

```
using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoDB.Driver;

protected static IMongoClient client;
protected static IMongoDatabase db;

        public async void Insert()
        {
        client = new MongoClient();
        db = client.GetDatabase("Database");

        string json = "[";

        foreach (CsvObjects.Connections e in connectionsList)
        {
            json += "{";
            json += "\"DateTime\":\"" + e.DateTime + "\",";
            json += "\"Value\":\"" + e.Value + "\",";
            json += "},";
        }

        json += "]";

        MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument document = MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonSerializer.Deserialize<BsonDocument>(json);

        var collection = db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("data");
        await collection.InsertOneAsync(document);
```

I made an arraylist with data I want to insert into the mongodb, I tried to make a json and insert it with the InsertOneAsync method but I got the deserialization error. There might be an easier way to do this but I have no idea how.

I tried some other stackoverflow threads about this topic but without avail.

> "Cannot deserialize a 'BsonDocument' from BsonType 'Array'"

Comment: Thank you all for your help. It's working now. Right now I only have one problem, it takes over 30 minutes to process all miljon objects. I am trying to use the insert many Async method. But I don't know how to insert the Arraylist.  

var FoodCollection = _db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("Foods");
            foreach (CsvObjects.Food e in foodList)
            {
                await FoodCollection.InsertOneAsync(e.ToBsonDocument());
            }
            Console.WriteLine("done inserting Food documents");

Answer (score 1):

You may not even have to create a JSON string besides being verbose it's prone to errors.  You can use the ToBsonDocument extension found in MongoDB.Bson instead, for example.

```
using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoDB.Driver;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Example
{
    class FooItem
    {
        public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }

    class InsertTest
    {
        protected static IMongoClient _client;
        protected static IMongoDatabase _db;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            _client = new MongoClient();
            _db = _client.GetDatabase("Database");
            MainAsync(args).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        }

        static IEnumerable<FooItem> GetList()
        {
            yield return new FooItem
            {
                DateTime = DateTime.Now,
                Value = "I am foo 1"
            };
            yield return new FooItem
            {
                DateTime = DateTime.Now,
                Value = "I am foo 2"
            };
        }

        static async Task MainAsync(string[] args)
        {
            var collection = _db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("data");
            foreach (var item in GetList())
            {
                await collection.InsertOneAsync(item.ToBsonDocument());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This yields this result

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("565e70208af88628ecb3237d"), "DateTime" : ISODate("2015-12-02T04:14:24.789Z"), "Value" : "I am foo 1" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("565e70228af88628ecb3237e"), "DateTime" : ISODate("2015-12-02T04:14:26.511Z"), "Value" : "I am foo 2" }
```

Answer (score 0):

From the error message, you are trying to deserialize and array of JSON documents into a single document.

Instead, either perform your Deserialize and InsertOneAsync's inside your foreach loop or create another loop that inserts 1 document at a time.

Also, use the StringBuilder class!  string is immutable so for each item in connectionsList your current code is creating 2n + 2 strings!

Answer (score -1):

await collection.InsertOneAsync(item.ToBsonDocument());

"await" is the keyword if not where it is initialize

Comment: what do you mean?